# Azure Cloud Services Running 4 hours straight

Tags: azure, cloud, wcf

I've deployed some WCF services to the Azure Cloud Services, but it shows every day that it runs for 4 hours, when no-one is using the services. The only thing I thought was maybe it was hackers trying to find vulnerabilities, but I would imagine that Microsoft has something for those types of attacks in place. Am I right? I had thought that these services are off, until you call them and then they spin on and shut off when idle. Is there something I can do to configure this? I can't find anything on the portal to do this. I'm new to the whole cloud thing, I'm coming from working on actual servers, so it's a big change for me.

***Update***

So I was reviewing another post in [stackoverflow.com](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14988323/what-constitutes-a-compute-hour-or-cost-hour) with the admin and some of those hours appear to be from our deployment in the way that Microsoft calculates their "hours". My brain was not functioning properly last night, but I found the answer to my question. I just wanted to know if Microsoft handles regular server attacks, or would we have to deal with that. Apparently they do in some way, without any details I found this [other post on stackoverflow.com](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13771176/what-happens-if-a-ddos-attack-hits-windows-azure-web-sites). So that's basically it.

Comment: There is absolutely no way we can help you with the amount of details you've provided. Please edit your question and provide as many details as possible.

Comment: @EEAA I see your point, but this is all that I've done....1) create web service....2) deploy web service to azure cloud services.....3)the services are not being utilized, they just don't turn off.....I'm not sure what other details I can provide. That's everything that's been done (default settings have been deployed too, no modifications to the default configurations for the cloud services). I guess I could delete this question and try a MS Azure forum. I was trying to find a azure stack exchange, but couldn't find one.

Comment: @EEAA found my answer. Give an army vet a break. I'm doing my hardest to provide for my family. I know I didn't make sense last night, but I haven't had much sleep this past month. I just don't know how that rant of an answer that you gave would have contributed when I had stated "...I would imagine that Microsoft has something for those types of attacks in place. Am I right?" That sort of attitude is what kills this community and why lots of people think it's just a game for people to collect points. It just seems the higher the points someone has, the more of an insane response someone gets.

Comment: My "rant" of an answer was appropriate given the information provided. Your edit makes what you were looking for much more clear, and if you'd asked that question last night, you would have had much better luck. Honestly, I couldn't care less about the fake internet points. Really. I participate here becase 1) I learn a *ton* from doing so. (Even from this question) and 2) To help people out with and to advocate for solid, well-thought-through technology solutions.

Comment: Well I hope so, and that's why I did the update, because several hours later I see that it didn't make sense. It's futile to argue further, but really do hope it's not all about the points for you.

Answer (score 2):

Azure's Cloud Services (web and worker roles) run instances of your defined web and worker role templates (or wcf web role, which you might be using, given this is about WCF). It will run a minimum of one instance for each role. This is by design for Cloud Services, and you pay the per-hour cost for the given VM size (and quantity) selected for each role, whether burning 0% or 100% CPU. You cannot scale in to zero instances of a web/worker role. And even if Cloud Services supported this, you'd then have periods where your service was offline (unavailable).

You may choose to shut down the entire Cloud Service (you can stop it without deleting it), but again, you'll be completely offline when you do this.

There are other ways to spin up service periodically in Azure, such as Virtual Machines (you can start and stop each instance, as you wish).

Comment: Thanks for the information. Found my answer. Sorry was not very clear last night. Been having a lot of long nights. Just wanted to know if Azure handles regular attacks on a server.